# How to submit after jquery regex validations complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I stop submit button if this `UserRegistration()` function not complete its regex validations and `.ajax callback`. Just only stop submit button not show the success result with Ajax. After validations complete submit can send data. I try to use some methods like preventing event returning true or false but can't do it. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
function UserRegistration() {   

    //Input validations
    $('.validate-inputs').keyup(function (event) {
        
        event.preventDefault();     

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'fullname') {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#vfullname").html("Please enter a name.");
                $("#vfullname").removeClass();
                $("#vfullname").addClass("text-warning");
                $(this).removeClass();
                $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-warning");
            }
            else if (!isValidFullname($(this).val())) {
                $("#vfullname").html("Please enter a valid name.");
                $("#vfullname").removeClass();
                $("#vfullname").addClass("text-info");
                $(this).removeClass();
                $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info");
            } else {
                $("#vfullname").html("");
                $(this).removeClass();
                $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
            }
        } 
    }); 

    //Ajax validations
    $("#register-form").keyup(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registercontrol.php",
            data: {
                fullname: fullname,
                username: username,
                email: email,
                password: password
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.une) {
                    $("#vusername").html(result['une']);
                    $("#vusername").removeClass();
                    $("#vusername").addClass("text-danger");
                    $("#username").removeClass();
                    $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
                }

                if (result.me) {
                    $("#vemail").html(result['me']);
                    $("#vemail").removeClass();
                    $("#vemail").addClass("text-danger");
                    $("#email").removeClass();
                    $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

**Html form**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validations.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        UserRegistration();
    })
</script>

<form id="register-form" role="form" method="post" action="registercontrol.php" autocomplete="off">    
                                    
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Name">            
    <span id="vfullname"></span>                                                                
       
                                            
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Username">
    <span id="vusername"></span>                                    
    
                                    
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Email">
    <div id="vemail"></div>                                 
                                                    
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Password">
    <span id="vpassword"></span>                                        
              
                                    
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create an Account" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">                                
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add your `form` HTML here please. And how are you calling this function `UserRegistration` ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I added. I called it HTML page in `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: See the working solution below and and some explanation for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to stop user to click submit button is to use `disabled` on the your submit button

Initially disable the button when page loads - once your `ajax` validation is `completed` just enable the submit button n `ajax` success function for the user to click and submit the registration form

You can do the same thing for all the `if's` condition just disbale the button if validation criteria is not met.

Run snippet below to see to see it working.

```js
function UserRegistration() {

  //Input validations
  $('.validate-inputs').keyup(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'fullname') {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
      
         //Disable submit button
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled')
        
        
        $("#vfullname").html("Please enter a name.");
        $("#vfullname").removeClass();
        $("#vfullname").addClass("text-warning");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-warning");
        //}
        /* else if (!isValidFullname($(this).val())) {
            $("#vfullname").html("Please enter a valid name.");
            $("#vfullname").removeClass();
            $("#vfullname").addClass("text-info");
            $(this).removeClass();
            $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-info"); */
      } else {
        //Enable Submit button
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false)
        
        $("#vfullname").html("");
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("form-control form-control-user border-success");
      }
    }
  });

  //Ajax validations
  $("#register-form").keyup(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "registercontrol.php",
      data: {
        fullname: fullname,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
      
        //Enable submit button
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false)
        
        if (result.une) {
          $("#vusername").html(result['une']);
          $("#vusername").removeClass();
          $("#vusername").addClass("text-danger");
          $("#username").removeClass();
          $("#username").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
        }

        if (result.me) {
          $("#vemail").html(result['me']);
          $("#vemail").removeClass();
          $("#vemail").addClass("text-danger");
          $("#email").removeClass();
          $("#email").addClass("form-control form-control-user border-danger");
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

UserRegistration()
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register-form" role="form" method="post" action="registercontrol.php" autocomplete="off">

  <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Name">
  <span id="vfullname"></span>


  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Username">
  <span id="vusername"></span>


  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Email">
  <div id="vemail"></div>

  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-user validate-inputs" placeholder="Password">
  <span id="vpassword"></span>


  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Hesap Oluştur" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It's working but why its not works with else if condition

Comment: @Ulrich are you sure you added the code disable button .prop in the else if condition ?

Comment: Yea, i know why its not working. I tried to put disable, true in else after main if condtion. Main condition is just for checking element id. thats why its not working. I just tried to make submit disabled out of if else and make enabled in just else condition. But I have to recreate my if else condtions for this again. But I will do it. I have gained an idea thanks to you now Help Angel :)